# How to test if a number is an integer or a float that only has a zero after the decimal?

Tags: python, numbers

**Just to clarify, I am Using Python 2.7**

I need to check if "x" is an integer (for example 7) or if "x" is a float with only a zero at the end of the decimal (for example 7.0). I have a format so all I need help on is the code.

```
    x = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")

    if type(x) == int or __________ :
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My goal is if you plug in a 5 or  5.0, it will return True, but is you plug in  a 6.7, it will return False.

The **underscores (empty spaces)** are where I need to add the code. I tried many different attempts at this but they all failed.

Comment: "I have a format so all I need is the code." Step 1: Write the code

Comment: But I don't know the code.

Comment: Step 1: Learn to code

Comment: Python ***1.0!?*** I sincerely hope not.

Comment: I learn from Codecadamy and they only teach python 1.0

Comment: [This page](https://www.quora.com/Is-Codecademy-a-good-website-to-learn-Python) says otherwise.

Comment: Hell, Python 1.0 didn't even have True or False. It didn't even have `list`. It is so old, python.org doesn't even have the documentation any more. It is so old, it doesn't support Windows. It is a historical relic, and I am pretty confident you are not using it.

Comment: sorry, I am mistaken

Comment: Codecademy should fire the author of that ridiculously awful code (in other words: I don't believe that that's from Codecademy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple test, which works because Python integers are unlimited in resolution:

```
return float(x) == int(float(x))
```

The result from `raw_input` isn't a number, it's a string. That's why it has to be converted to `float` first.

Comment: What exactly does the int(x) do?

Comment: @Alex it converts `x` to the equivalent integer. If `x` is a floating point number, it will be truncated.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're exceeding the max float size. (~1.8e308 on my system). I don't think you mean to be multiplying a string by an integer, that's yielding a string that contains four hundred `1`s.

Comment: @KalZekdor You're wrong, that's exactly what I meant to do.

Comment: @StefanPochmann if it's possible for it to be a float, then it should respect the range for floats. Your own answer has the same problem.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, converting float infinity to an integer yields an overflow error, so that's what's going on. If you're dealing with numbers that large you shouldn't be using floats.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why? I don't think so. But really I think the OP should show us the real task. What they did show is so ridiculously awful that I can't believe that's from Codecademy. Probably the real task differs and `x` is already an int or a float and the OP made up the `raw_input` statement themselves.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `.is_integer()` on a float infinity yields false, period.

Comment: @KalZekdor *"If you're dealing with numbers that large you shouldn't be using floats"* - Tell that to Mark :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Fair enough, but my point was that dealing with exceptionally large numbers is, well, exceptional, and requires particular handling. For 99.999% of cases, though, it's not something to worry about.

Comment: @KalZekdor And... apparently I'm right. I googled a bit, looks like Codecademy really just provides the function name `is_int` and says `x` is already a number ([this might be the actual problem text](https://github.com/Manish-Giri/CodeAcademy/blob/master/Python/Challenges/Practice/3.py) (above someone's solution), so the OP indeed made all that horrible code up themselves, as I suspected.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, if only floats had a method like "[is_integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)"...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a value, r, that is a float/real number,

```
r = 3.33333
```

Then the value of the following is non-zero when r is a float/real (non integer),

```
f = r - int(r)
print r -int(r)
```

However, a regex may be a more general solution, as you can search for matching \d*.\0*[1-9]{1} as float, and \d+.?0* being interpreted as integer.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful!

Comment: "Regex would be a better solution"? For checking whether a number is an integer? You cannot be serious. Regex is far slower, less readable and more prone to errors than some basic math. You've unwillingly proven this with your two regexes: The int pattern would match _any_ single-character string, and your float pattern would match strings like "a1".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Regex was example, and well, yeah, unless the number was 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003